# How to make matchpairs not match closing '>' in "<(>)" while still matching it in "<()>"?

Tags: delimiter-matching

I'm using `set matchpairs+=<:>` with my C++ code, and it works great. But there are some cases where it is not quite there, like this C++ code:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<int X> typename std::enable_if<(X>9),int>::type func() { return 5; }
int main() { func<10>(); }
```

Here, if you put the cursor on the `<` after `enable_if`, the `>` in `X>9` will be highlighted. Of course it makes sense from the perspective of Vim, which isn't a C++ compiler nor an IDE. But is there any easy way to make it not match pairs broken by non-closed parentheses? I.e. I'd like `<()>` to match the closing angle bracket, and `<(>)` not to.

Comment: just curious, are you working with matchit ? https://github.com/tmhedberg/matchit, since it often solves this kind of problems, but i am not sure if it will help in your case

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo no, just plain vim.

Answer (score 1):

`matchit` will most probably not do this for you.  You probably want to write a small wrapper function for `%`, which identifies the character under your cursor with:

```
let curChar = char2nr(matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.'))
```

followed by a couple of simple nested tests such that:

```
test-1: if curChar is not `<`, then
     act simply the way `%` would
else 
    test-2:  if whatever lies between current `<` and following `>` contains one of ( or ) or { or } or [ or ], then
        do not jump or highlight
    else
        jump or highlight
```

which means , ***get scripting in vim*** ...

Let us know how this goes.